# Decrypt - Encrypt crypto-js

Tags: javascript, algorithm, encryption, aes, des

I am trying to get crypto-js library to encrypt/decrypt a simple message, please see the following jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/6gunq2nx/)

```
<script>
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("this is some test", "770A8A65DA156D24EE2A093277530142");
    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, "770A8A65DA156D24EE2A093277530142");
    alert(decrypted);
</script>
```

**The problem** is that, it is not decrypting the message properly, I have tried AES and DES but both do not work, what im I doing wrong? please see below screenshot

[image: AES]

Comment: Hint: the numerical equivalents of "t", "h", and "i" are 116, 104, and 105; in hexadecimal that's 74, 68, 69.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's almost correct. The string you get is a hexadecimal representation of your original string. Try to convert it like this:

```
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, "770A8A65DA156D24EE2A093277530142").toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

forked jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1qgzk9j8/

Comment: Awesome, converting to string was not mentioned in the example:) thanks alot!

Comment: This took me out of a debugging frenzy! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try this :-

```
// Replace this with user input (only user should know the passphrase which can be used to decrypt the message)
var passphrase = '770A8A65DA156D24EE2A093277530142';

// Some content that we want to crypt
var content = 'this is some test';

// Use CryptoJS.AES to encrypt content using AES (Advanced Encryption Standard)
 var encryptedContent = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(content, passphrase);

// Use CryptoJS.AES also to decrypt content
 var decryptedContent = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedContent, passphrase).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

alert(encryptedContent);
alert(decryptedContent);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6gunq2nx/1/)